# Getting extra information from relationship table in JDO

Tags: java, database-design, jdo

I am modelling a database for use in a sql only application for now.

I have three tables

```
Company 
company_id,name

Contact
contact_id, name

rel_contact_company
company_id, contact_id, is_employee
```

It's a many to many relationship but the relation ship table has extra information about the relationship (is_employee).

Is it possible to query this information from jdo using normal relationships or is it better to create two relationship tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/guides/jdo/many_many_attributed/index.html